# How to translate root specific resource declaration from Rails 2 to Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, custom-routes

I'm migrating an application from Rails 2.3.5 to Rails 3.2.8. 
I have this route from the Rails 2 app that is giving me headaches:

```
  map.resources :soumission_vt,
                :path_prefix => "/soumission/VT/:page_id", :as => 'police/:action/:id',
                :requirements => {:page_id => /\S+/}
```

wich generates the following:

```
soumission_vt_index GET    /soumission/VT/:page_id/police/:action/:id(.:format)               {:controller=>"soumission_vt"}
                    POST   /soumission/VT/:page_id/police/:action/:id(.:format)               {:controller=>"soumission_vt"}
new_soumission_vt   GET    /soumission/VT/:page_id/police/:action/:id/new(.:format)           {:controller=>"soumission_vt"}
edit_soumission_vt  GET    /soumission/VT/:page_id/police/:action/:id/:id/edit(.:format)      {:controller=>"soumission_vt"}
soumission_vt       GET    /soumission/VT/:page_id/police/:action/:id/:id(.:format)           {:controller=>"soumission_vt"}
                                    PUT    /soumission/VT/:page_id/police/:action/:id/:id(.:format)           {:controller=>"soumission_vt"}
                    DELETE /soumission/VT/:page_id/police/:action/:id/:id(.:format)           {:controller=>"soumission_vt"}
```

I translated it this way in Rails 3:

```
  scope '/soumission/VT/:page_id', :constraints => {:page_id => /\S+/} do
    resources :soumission_vt, :as => 'police/:action/:id'
  end
```

but I am getting an Invalid route name: 'police/:action/:id_index'...

So is there a way to reproduce those routes in Rails 3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After one try, I succeeded to make it work with the following lines of code:

```
scope '/soumission/VT/:page_id' do
    get 'police/new', controller: :soumission_vt, action: :new, as: :new_soumission_vt
end
```

Hope this will help you finish your migration in time !

;)